# Highchart area range on a plot column

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I would like to set my area range (the blue horizontal bar) only on the red bar (fidding the width of the red bar) but I cannot find a solution to do this.  Plot band don't work because it's full width on x axis. Could you help me please ?

On this try I managed to set the area range (blue horizontal bar) but it created another entry on X axis ("1"), I want to keep only the first entry "Omburu" with the same disposition of yellow, orange and red bar. With additionnal horizontal blue bar on the red bar who is set between to values following "Puissance kW" scale.

The JSFiddle is here : https://jsfiddle.net/poloh11/1qzfgopy/11/

Thanks a lot

[image: Chart]

```
{
    name: 'Range',
    data: [
        [1000, 1500],[1000, 1500]
    ],
    type: 'arearange',
    lineWidth: 0,
    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
    fillOpacity: 0.3,
    marker: {
        enabled: false
    },
    yAxis: 1
}
```

Comment: I can't say I understand what you want to do. Could you make a mockup in paint? And/Or explain a bit more what result you expect?

Comment: Thanks a lot ewolden to have a look on this, I changed the description to be more clear. If it's not enough I can do a paint. Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `columnrage` series instead. It has common properties with `column` series (`pointRange`, `pointPadding` etc.) that allow to adjust it similarly. The following configuration works for me:

```
{
  name: 'Range',
  data: [
    [1000, 1500]
  ],
  type: 'columnrange',
  lineWidth: 0,
  color: 'rgba(149,206,255,0.7)',
  marker: {
    enabled: false
  },
  yAxis: 1,
  pointPlacement: 0.3,
  pointRange: 0.33,
  borderWidth: 0
}
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9czvmhsx/

**API reference:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9czvmhsx/